# Paste a full SVG content to CKEditor - not working

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I tried to paste a full SVG content into the CKEditor Full HTML Source

But it gets corrupted and not working

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by disabling the content filters at

`http://<your website>/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full`

and choose `Advanced content filter` and select `disabled`

Warning: you should create a separate filter for ckeditor and allow only few trusted users to use Unfiltered Full HTML.